# SwiftUI styling (List color & UIPageControl height)

Tags: swiftui, uipagecontrol, swiftui-tabview

Dears,

given the following View :

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

var regions = ["Bayern","Brandenburg","Hamburg","Hessen","Saarland"]
var tabs = ["home","menu_book","photo","audio","movie","view_cozy"]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedRegion: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                        LazyHStack {
                            PageView().padding(0)
                        }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Text("MyApp")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Button(action:{},label :{Text("Mail")})
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Picker("Select", selection: $selectedRegion) {
                        ForEach(regions, id: \.self) { region in
                            Text(region)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
//            Button(action: {},label: {Text("Test Button")})
            Image("home")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(0)
                .frame(width:20,height: 20)
                .border(Color.blue)
            ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { btn in
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                print("Button clicked : Tab\(tab)_btn_\(btn)")
                        },
                            label: {
                            Text("Tab\(tab)_btn_\(btn)").font(.system(size: 12))
                        })
                        .background(SwiftUI.Color.pink)
                    }
                }
                .background(SwiftUI.Color.yellow)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(tab)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding(0)
                        .frame(width:20,height: 20)
                        .border(Color.blue)
//                    Text(tab)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .background(SwiftUI.Color.orange)
    }
    
    init() {
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
        UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = .blue
        UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
//        UIPageControl.appearance().transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
        
//        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .orange
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to set the background color of my list to a specific color (let's say orange) and reduce the height of the page indicator (that bar on the bottom which has the all the icons).

what I've tried you can see in the code comments. Anyway, whatever I do I end up with the following view :
[image][image]
The idea would be that on the second tab (the one with the home icon) the list background should have the same background color as on the first tab.
The icons are SVG (at least that's what I've imported in Xcode). How can I reduce the size of that bottom bar ? (Icons seem too big)

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a bit of difficulty getting your code to run in a way that looked anything like your screenshots using an iPhone 14 simulator and iOS 17. These changes helped:

1. Remove the `ScrollView` and `LazyHStack` around `PageView`:

```swift
NavigationView {
//    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
//        LazyHStack {
            PageView() //.padding(0)
//        }
//    }
```

2. Don't set the frame width and height using `UIScreen.main.bounds` (which is deprecated anyway).

```swift
//    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

3. Turn the home page into a full page by wrapping with a `ZStack`, using a color to fill all the space available:

```swift
ZStack {
    SwiftUI.Color.orange
    Image("home")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        // .padding(0)
        .frame(width:20, height: 20)
        .border(Color.blue)
}
```

This way, you don't need to set a background on the `TabView`, which means the navigation bar does not get an orange background.

```swift
//    .background(SwiftUI.Color.orange)
```

The console was also reporting a problem with the `Picker`, because:

> the selection "0" is invalid and does not have an associated tag

but I didn't try to fix this.

So with the changes above, it looked like this (using improvised images):

[image: HomeOrange]

What's interesting, is that the images in the tab bar are tiny and the height of the bar itself is also pretty minimal. I am using standard system images and actually, I couldn't find a way to make them bigger. So maybe you need to try re-sizing the natural size of your .svg icons. Otherwise, I don't think you have much control over the way the page indicators are shown.

You get bigger images if you use `.tabViewStyle(.automatic)`, but only 3 images are actually shown, the rest are in a "More..." menu:

[image: AutomaticTabBar]

As for the backgrounds to the lists, you can set a background color for the list rows using `.listRowBackground` and you can hide the gray background of the `List` using `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`. When these changes are all combined, the `List` items look like this:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(0..<20) { btn in
        // content as before
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(Color.yellow)
```

[image: YellowList]

Here is the fully adapted code that I ended up with, in case it's useful for reference.

```
struct PageView: View {
//    let tabs = ["home","menu_book","photo","audio","movie","view_cozy"]
    let tabs = ["house.fill", "book.fill", "photo", "headphones", "film", "fireplace"]

    var body: some View {

        TabView {
//            Button(action: {},label: {Text("Test Button")})
            ZStack {
                SwiftUI.Color.orange
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding(0)
                    .frame(width:20, height: 20)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
            ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { btn in
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                print("Button clicked : Tab\(tab)_btn_\(btn)")
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text("Tab\(tab)_btn_\(btn)").font(.system(size: 12))
                            })
                        .background(SwiftUI.Color.pink.opacity(0.2))
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(SwiftUI.Color.yellow)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: tab)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
//                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .border(Color.blue)
//                    Text(tab)
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }

    init() {
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
        UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = .blue
        UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
//        UIPageControl.appearance().transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)

//        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .orange
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let regions = ["Bayern", "Brandenburg", "Hamburg", "Hessen", "Saarland"]

    @State var selectedRegion: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PageView()
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text("MyApp")
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Button {} label: {
                            Text("Mail")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Picker("Select", selection: $selectedRegion) {
                            ForEach(regions, id: \.self) { region in
                                Text(region)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you find something useful in all that.

Comment: Many thx. It helped a lot !
Obviously in my previous example I chose those stringent colors just to be certain that I see  a difference.
Based on could set now the List background color and also to adjust the height the page indicator.
I found it strange that I can resize the image if I use it on the first tab but not when it in that page indicator (that bottom bar, whatever it is called).
Anyways, the interface looks much better

Comment: Would you be so kind just to try to reduce the length of the lists ?
I mean put fewer items in the list ... once the list doesn't reach 'till the end I got the white background again... I never in my life had such a hard time to set a background color of an application.

Comment: I changed the number of items to 1 but it still works for me. I am running on an iPhone 14 simulator with iOS 17. Did you remember to set a background behind the ```List```? You could maybe try putting it on the ```ForEach``` instead.

Comment: Why on earth would stackoverflow put a limit on the length of the comment ??
Or at least this restrictive ? I would like to post here the new (reduced) version of the code but it just doesn't fit :(
Anyways, I wonder, could it it possible the the simulation software makes such big different ? I'm using iPhone 8 with iOS 14.4...

Comment: I'm going crazy. Is there ANY way to make the background of this list blue ?
(iPhone8/IOS14.4 ... if that makes any difference)



import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {}, label: {Text("One")}).listRowBackground(Color.red)
            Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Two")})
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}

Comment: it does seem to depend on the iOS version.
Based on my googleing, people do "scrollContentBackground" on the list but in iOS 14.4 (the latest I have access to) that is not available.